# JQuery pagecontainer change odd behaviour?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

That how I am trying to do the application flow :

1. Login checker : Basically to check if `window.localStorage["id"] != undefined` then redirect to the main page "index.html" `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "index.html");` else `$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "register.html");` , which contains main menu to navigate through the application functions
2. Main menu is just a navigation function as below

index.html code

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/menu.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home" class="bg_main" style="padding-top: 1%;">
   <div date-role="content">
      <div id="mainmenu"> 
         <img id="item1" class="menuitem" src="images/menu1.png" />
         <img id="item2" class="menuitem" src="images/menu2.png" />
         <img id="item3"  class="menuitem" src="images/menu3.png" />
         <img id="item4" class="menuitem" src="images/menu4.png" />
         <img id="item5" class="menuitem" src="images/menu5.png" />
         <img id="item6" class="menuitem" src="images/menu6.png" />
         <img id="item7" class="menuitem" src="images/menu7.png" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

login

3. We have also same menu item related in bottom navigation bar in each page, and ID of these items is exactly same as the main menu

Like this footer code in each page

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a"> 
  <img id="home" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/bt_home.png"/>
  <img id="item1" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item1.png"/>
  <img id="item2" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item2.png"/>
  <img id="item3" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item3.png"/>
  <img id="item4" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item4.png"/>
  <img id="item5" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item5.png"/>
  <img id="item6" class="imgh im40 left top_txt" src="images/item6.png"/>
  <img id="item7" class="imgh im40 left top_txt active" src="images/item7.png"/>
  </div>
```

4. What I did is included the menu.js header in all pages as following

Code of menu.js

```
 $(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {

    /* created page */
    var createdPage = $(e.target);

    /* find element within it
       remove previous listener
       add new listener */

    createdPage.find("#item1").off("click").on("click", function () {
        run();
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "item1.html");
    });

    createdPage.find("#home").off("click").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "index.html");
    });});
```

code of item1 page
I include a function.js inside the header and inside the function this code

```
<html>
<head>
   <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/menu.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/function.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div data-role="page" id="item1">
      <div date-role="content"></div><div id="button1"></div>
   </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

function.js

```
    function run()
{$("#button1").off("click").on("click", function () {
        //do something
    });}
```

below are code of the main page

```
 <div id="mainmenu"> 
             <img id="home" class="menuitem" src="images/home.png" />
             <img id="item1" class="menuitem" src="images/menu1.png" />
             <img id="item2" class="menuitem" src="images/menu2.png" />
             <img id="item3"  class="menuitem" src="images/menu3.png" />
             <img id="item4" class="menuitem" src="images/menu4.png" />
             <img id="item5" class="menuitem" src="images/menu5.png" />
             <img id="item6" class="menuitem" src="images/menu6.png" />
             <img id="item7" class="menuitem" src="images/menu7.png" />
          </div>
```

The problems now are :

- The login is no longer working
- When navigation to one of the items which contains another function with `click` events trigger some function is not working any more.
- Navigation from inside item1 to other pages is not working

Comment: You're duplicating click listeners by calling menu() on each pagecreate. Remove previous bindings before adding them again.

Comment: @Kolban Can you explain how to remove previous binding? you mean like this ?[code] $("#item7").off("click").on("click", function () {
      $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "item7.html");
   }); [/code]

Comment: Yes, as I have explained in my answer to your precious question. It's better to use classes not IDs because they might duplicate I DOM. Use this `$("#item1", this).off("click").on("click", function () { code });`.

Comment: @Omar I did exactly as you suggested but, with `$("#item1", this).off("click").on("click", function () { code });` but I didn't work , the item wasn't clickable so I changed to `$("#item1").off("click").on("click", function () { code });` it worked , but it is only allow two navigation , "Home->item1 and item1->home" and that it, when I am back to home it doesn't work in any item?

Comment: @omar I think I got it ,so initially I have to call it with out `.off` and then I call it with `.off` it is working better now thanks , can you please post answer?

Comment: @Omar : it is sometimes working and sometimes no :(, have no idea why

Comment: Use classes instead of IDs. IDs are duplicated in DOM. I'll show you how in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

Based on your updated question, redirecting using JQM Ajax navigation won't load any libraries you have in index.html nor in register.html. All libraries should be placed in `head` of first page that runs.

Another option, place libraries inside *page* div of index.html/register.html if you want them to be retrieved along with page's content.

In Single Page Model, jQuery Mobile parses first *page* div of each external file and neglects anything else.

---

Since you have the same menu in each page, you should specifically target the menu within page being created. You don't need to add `pagecreate` listener for each and every page, it can be done in one step.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {

    /* created page */
    var createdPage = $(e.target);

    /* find element within it
       remove previous listener
       add new listener */

    createdPage.find("#item1").off("click").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "item1.html");
    });

    createdPage.find("#item2").off("click").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "item2.html");
    });

    /* rest of items */
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6qur6gyq/)**

Comment: Any other scripts that already `on` in the delegated pages have are not working after applying your suggestion.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa if you have those scripts within `head` of external pages, they won't be loaded. Add all scripts of all pages in `head` of index file. They will be loaded one time only.

Comment: do you suggest to load the scripts in head of all pages ? because that already the case but still it is not loaded, I have even loaded the function within `createdPage.find("#item2").off("click").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "item2.html"); //called the function here and also didn't work
    });`

Comment: @MohamedMostafa can you update your question with your current code?

Comment: Thanks @Omar  for your effort

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I am sure what are you saying is the best answer, but I cannot figure out exactly what to do, I am bit confused, from this JQuery thing, it doesn't make sense for me, it is really blur for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64202/discussion-between-omar-and-mohamed-mostafa).

Comment: @mohamedmostafa join chat